# CSV parse using aws athena

Tags: java, csv, amazon-web-services

I am parsing csv file using AWS athena from java code.
Some columns  in csv are of date type and one column has comma in the value.

If  the athena table is created with

`ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe'`

then it is unable to parse the column with comma correctly

However it parses correctly if I use

`ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'`

But the issue with `OpenCSVSerde` is that it requires all columns to be of string data type and I need to carry out date operations in the query so can't use `OpenCSVSerde`.

Any other solution?
Please help!

Comment: did you find out the solution

Answer (score 4):

That's how this two SerDes are designed, you should only use the `LazySimpleSerDe` in cases when your data is relatively clean, for example, it does not have values enclosed in quotes or does not have delimiters in the value. And `OpenCSVSerde` works well for deserializing CSV files that have values enclosed in quotes; however, all columns in the table are of STRING data type. More info [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/csv.html)

So in your case, as your data is not clean, the only way to parse it and have loaded into Athena is to use `OpenCSVSerde`. And if you need to use date operations you need to manually convert/parse the date strings into a date object, which is fairly easy to do with `date_parse` function.

So say if you have following string data in your date type column:

```
11/13/2017
11/14/2017
11/15/2017
11/16/2017
```

You can use the following query to select date in the range

```
select * from somedb.sometable where date_parse(createdate, '%m/%d/%Y') between DATE'2017-11-14' and DATE'2017-11-16';
```

Comment: I've data like below and OpenCSVSedre, doesn't handle it.

100,sample <(>&<)> O sample ? PILE UP - 3 sample,20,7^M$
101,sample- 4/52$
sample$
CM,21,7^M$
102,sample AT 3PM,22,4^M$